# Querying changed model attributes in rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, callback, task

I'm performing a periodic rake task to update attributes in my `User` model. I'd like to execute a Mailer if a particular attribute has changed, but I can't call the `attribute_changed?` module as it doesn't know the instance to query - usually you'd do this in the model with an `after_save` callback.

So I have this:

```
task :my_task => :environment do    
  User.all.each do |user|

     @howmanythings = user.things.size
     user.update_attribute(:total_things, @howmanythings)

     user.save

     //THIS IS THE BIT THAT DOES NOT WORK:

     if user.total_things_changed? == true
       SEND MAILER
     end

  end    
end
```

At the moment, user.`total_things_changed?` is returning `false`, regardless of whether the rake task has updated that attribute. In short, how do I execute an after_save callback (or equivalent) within a task? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ActiveRecord::Dirty`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Dirty) tracks *unsaved* attribute changes. The moment you save the model, `foo_changed?` methods will start returning `false`.

Note that `update_attribute` saves the model.

You could probably do something like

```
@howmanythings = user.things.size
user.total_things = user.things.size

if user.total_things_changed? == true
  # SEND MAILER
end

user.save
```

to make it work like you expect.